# AIR SDK: want to move flash cs6 app to RCT6378W2 RCA tablet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, publishing

I'm trying to move an app created in flash professional cs6 to my 7" RCA tablet (serial number:RCT6378W2), but when I try to publish it, flash doesn't register the device as connected at all.  The device is connected to my PC running windows 7 64 bit via USB to mini-USB. The device shows up in the computer panel as if it is connected. I have USB debugging activated on the device, I have the android SDK as well just to be sure I'm running the appropriate drivers to make up for the lack of drivers built into the RCA tablets for USB.  The device runs android version 4.2.2 with jelly bean. I've already created the APK file through FLASH from the SWF.  So, after all that I've been trying to bypass publishing and simply use the AIR SDK to download the app to the device using ADT commands and arguments.

adt -installApp -platform android -device RCT6378W2 -package C:\users\me\Desktop\FILE.apk

the command line returns either one of the following errors:

invalid argument

invalid device

To be clear, flash won't recognize the device when publishing.  I've entered all of the appropriate info in the publishing settings, created a certificate, I even have the APK file ready to go saved on my desktop.

Does anyone have any experience with this situation, is the tablet simply not able to handle what I'm asking? Am I approaching this the wrong way?  Any thoughts at all are appreciated.

Comment: when you run: 'adb devices' from the SDK does your tablet show up? And what version of Android are you running?

Comment: I don't want to utilize ABD commands at all, unless I have to use ADT.  However, I do have it setup.  abd devices outputs:

Comment: List of devices attached.   and nothing else.  I'm using jelly bean android version 4.2.2

Comment: *ADB, i mean.  adb devices doesn't output any errors, but it also doesn't list any devices, it simply says, "List of devices attached", and thats it. I would also like to avoid rooting the device at all costs.  Not even sure if that would help, I'm new to this process, I mean like a new born new.

Comment: And for clarity sake, when you said run adb devices from the SDK, you mean having setup adb with the SDK and running commands on the command line that is accessed from the start menu in windows, right?

Comment: And of course the correct environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running adb with the 'devices' keyword and NOT getting any devices listed should tell you that you DON'T have a suitable USB driver installed.

Try the 'universal' driver found here:
http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

Restart your computer for good luck and then run adb again. Make sure that your tablet is connected to your PC and tat your cable is good. When your device is finally recognized by adb you can then see if you still have a publishing problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've tried rebooting with other drivers, but with no luck, but that one did it.  Thanks for the assist, Craig.